# time format "ls" in MacOSX

Tags: linux, mac-osx, posix

I have a Apple server, and when I use `ls -alFt`

output shows:

```
"drwxrwxrwx   267 admin  www        9078 Mar 31  2010 3/"
```

and

```
"drwxrwxrwx   483 admin  www       16422 Jul  9 09:58 26/"
```

what is the real time?

I'm looking for older folders to move it, but I don't understand the output format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` only shows the creation time if the file was recently made (6 months, according to `man ls`), otherwise it shows the year.  If you want to see full information on a file or directory use `stat`.  It's manpage has examples on how to combine stat with sort to order things around by modification time.

What you probably want, though, is `find . -mtime +365d` with a suitable age in there in place of 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

cmiiw

```
 -t      Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the operands by lexicographical order.
```

"drwxrwxrwx   267 admin  www        9078 Mar 31  2010 3/"    <== older

"drwxrwxrwx   483 admin  www       16422 Jul  9 09:58 26/"   <== newer

if you using ls -alFt, so the first line is the newest